# Catch exception in async Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm working in C# (console application).

In my program, I have to contact a httpClient. First I check if the client is responding using `GetAsync`. So my request method is async, making my Task async.

When client doesn't respond (or something else) it throw an exception but i'm unable to catch it.

I added a `ContinueWith` but it doesn't work. With a breackpoint I saw that the piece of code is reached at the start of my Task so the exception is always null.

How can I solve this problem ?

There is my code :

```
static void Run()
{
    String urlRequest = "";
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

    Console.WriteLine($"Program running, press a key to stop");
    try
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass") })
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlRequest);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                bool serviceAvailable = await CheckService(client);
                if (serviceAvailable)
                {
                    bool doLoop = true;
                    while (doLoop)
                    {
                        // Do something

                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\ntask cancelled");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException($"Unable to contact service at {urlRequest}");
                }
            }

        }, ct).ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            if (tsk.Exception != null)
                throw tsk.Exception;
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
        cts.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log(e);
    }
}

static async Task<bool> CheckClient(HttpClient client)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check service Call ...");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("CheckService");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: All the `CheckClient` is actually telling you is that, a short time ago, the service was responding at its `CheckService` endpoint. It does't tell you anything about whether the service is usable for any other purpose, or whether if you were to run the same check *now* you'd get the same answer. Given those constraints, is it actually *useful* to know this? Especially, if `//Do something` uses that service, it *doesn't* tell you that that will be able to succeed even *once*.

Comment: You should use Task.Run instead of task factory as apparently StartNew doesn't understand async delegates. More details here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are neither waiting for nor observing the result of your task. Assuming that you're running this against .Net 4.5 or later, the exception is there but it is going unnoticed.

So, first of all, you should `.Wait()` for your task to complete so that the calling code has a chance to observe the exception.

Generally speaking, you should avoid using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and prefer `Task.Run()` instead - see [Stephen Toub's explanation why](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/). But if you prefer to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` for whatever reason, then you additionally must first `.Unwrap()` the original task to obtain the actual task for which you want the result. (Do note that `.Unrwap()` is an extension method that is available for `Task<Task>` but not `Task`, so type the original variable accordingly; i.e., use `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`)

Comment: I replaced my `Task.Factory.StartNew() ` by a `Task.Run` and it works well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx) will be executed when the Task completed, with or without success.

In the case of success, your `tsk.Exception` in ContinueWith will be null.

Can you try :

```
.StartNew(...)
.ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            //thrown
        },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: I've try this but now the `if/throw` is never reached.

Comment: That means there aren't exceptions. you can try by thrwon an exception in CheckClient