# How to catch task user-defined exception that is inherited from task exception

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I defined a `CrawlerTimeoutException` that is inherited from task exception, when I throw it in my code, I can't catch it in the main thread, the code is below：

```
try
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    await Task.Delay(rand.Next(300, 1000));     //sims clicks
    var webcontent = await task.Crawl().Timeout(timeout);
}
catch (CrawlerTimeoutException)
{
   //do something       
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
   //do something
}
```

I threw the `CrawlerTimeoutException` in function `task.Crawl().Timeout(timeout)`;
the code is below：

```
public static Task<T> Timeout<T>(this Task<T> task, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        bool succ = task.Wait(millisecondsTimeout);
        if (succ)
            return task.Result;
        else
            throw new CrawlerTimeoutException("Task timeout");//here is the error
    });
}
```

when it times out, it will throw an exception, but the program will crash because it says: there is an exception that user-unhandled.
I don't know the reason, because I catch it in the main thread twice, but still, don't catch it.
If you know the reason, please tell me！
thanks so much!

Comment: I just replaced the `Task.Factory.StartNew() ` by `Task.run()` in `Timeout` function following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182766/catch-exception-in-async-task), but it didn't work for my program.

Comment: Are you just trying to timeout crawl? if so can you paste your Crawl Method

Comment: The `throw`/`catch` parts of the code look fine to me. Have you tried running it outside the debugger?